# How to make one label to set score on all view controllers?

Tags: ios

I have a label and I need it to show the score, coins ect on every ViewController, That means when The score changes it changes every where throughout the whole app...

I've tried to set a label to show score on the whole app but I cant figure out how!

Please help

This is what I have so Far In the View Controller:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
{
[super viewDidLoad];


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SettingsList.plist"]; //3

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SettingsList"ofType:@"plist"]; //5 //5

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
    }

    savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    nPoint = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"point"] intValue];
    [giftAmount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",nPoint]];

[self updateCurrencyBalance];
[self zoneLoading];
}

//adcolony
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateCurrencyBalance) name:kCurrencyBalanceChange object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(zoneReady) name:kZoneReady object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(zoneOff) name:kZoneOff object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(zoneLoading) name:kZoneLoading object:nil];
}

// Get currency balance from persistent storage and display it
- (void)updateCurrencyBalance {
NSNumber* wrappedBalance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCurrencyBalance];
NSUInteger balance = wrappedBalance && [wrappedBalance isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ? [wrappedBalance unsignedIntValue] : 0;
[giftAmount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", balance]];

[savedStock setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nPoint = balance] forKey:@"point"];
[savedStock writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

}
```

I have an action in the other PlayViewController which (minusus) -200 coins, but its not updating in the ViewController?

Comment: You mean you have added labels for each viewController?

Comment: Look into Key-Value Observing.

Comment: @EridBardhaj yes but each label must have the same information on it/ data!

Comment: I would look into NSUserdefaults.  Make your label on ALL view controllers and save your data to user defaults and load them back up each time a vc comes to view.

Comment: @Douglas Exactly Ive been trying to do that, should I make the labels the same names?

Comment: @Douglas or just the int.?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the names of the label are in the vc.  Just make sure that they all come from the same user default.  Like for score, on vc 1 take it from user defaults totalScore (or something) but the label might be called scoreForVC1.  On vc 2 the default will still be totalScore, but the label might be scoreForVC2.

Comment: If you look for a tutorial on NSUserdefaults it will show you how to set them up, save them, and access them.  Erid's answer is very close to what I mean.  There are some other things to consider with NSUserdefaults that what is in his answer.

Comment: @Jking What do you mean by this: I have an action in the other PlayViewController which (minusus) -200 coins, but its not updating in the ViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use NSNotificationCenter.

Add this code to all the places that change the value of your score:

```
- (void)updateScore:(NSNumber *)newValue
    // update the score
    self.score = newValue;

    // create an dictionary object containing the score to be sent with the notification
    NSMutableDictionary* userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [userInfo setObject:self.score forKey:@"score"];

    // Add this to send a notification to all the listeners in the whole app
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationScoreChanged" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

In the `viewDidLoad` methods of your view controllers, add this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];

    // Add this code to start receiving notifications (become a listener)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(scoreChanged:) name:@"NotificationScoreChanged" object:nil];
}
```

Then somewhere in your view controllers, add this method to update your UI:

```
- (void)scoreChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // retrieve the score results
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"NotificationScoreChanged"])
    {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSNumber *score = [userInfo objectForKey:@"score"];

        // and update your labels
        self.scoreLabel.text = [score description];
    }
```

And in your view controllers, add dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    //Unregister yourself (stop listening)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Note: you should adapt the code depending on how you store and retrieve your score. Ie, if you use NSUserDefaults (see @erid's answer), CoreDate, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSUserDefaults` for storing data (Data gets deleted only when program is removed from iOS Device or you can remove it manually).

## Storing Value on NSUserDefaults

```
//text is your label.text, and each time you change it, save it to user details
NSString *text;

//Store them to NSUserDefaults with a specific key
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:text forKey:@"label"];
```

## Getting value back

```
NSString *textValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"label" ];
label.text = textValue;
```

You can try adding `NSNotification` to your program to notificate you when the `NSString` you set to change the label changes, and there you can set this value to `NSUserDefaults`.

As David said this is not the best way to do this, but you have to read more about **Singletons** if you need to save your **DATA** until the app is closed.

Hope it helps

Comment: For something as transient as a score in a game, using NSUserDefaults is fairly counterproductive and this doesn't really answer the OP question of how to coordinate the changes.

Comment: I am sorry, but when you set the label you can also set the value on NSUserDefaults. Anyway If I edit question merged with @Van du Tran question, this achieves the goal that user wants, so that will be ok with you?

Comment: Using NSUserDefaults to store something that is frequently changing (extrapolating what kind of 'score' we're talking about here) is just generally bad advice because of the expense of synchronize and general access.  From the NSUserDefaults reference "The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences."

Comment: Good point, but I wasn't talking about performance. If it were for that I would give him Singletons or Extern Variables. I just gave him a simple answer, anyway judging from your opinion is right, but not referring to this question. Anyway this is my opinion, and I said why!